# Is there a way to automatically restart a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop

I've made a bash script in Linux to run on terminal. I was wondering if there was a way to make this script restart itself after x seconds, since it is a while-loop but after 10-12 cycles it stops unexpectedly, but by restarting the script in the same terminal I should be able to fix the problem.

Comment: post what you've tried in your script to get more accurate help.

Comment: Throw it all in a while loop. e.g. `while :; do ./your_script & pid=$!; sleep 10; kill $pid; done`

Comment: How it's dying matters. If it's completely dead, then it's dead -- you need something *outside* the script involved to start it in that case. Fortunately, modern operating systems provide process supervision systems, which are meant just for that purpose (starting processes on boot if wanted, restarting them if/when they die) -- so you should be using them.

Comment: Depending on your OS, your native process supervision mechanism may be Upstart, systemd, DJB daemontools, runit, supervisord, launchd, or something else -- but there's almost certainly one available.

Comment: Sure, but understand, that approach is a Bandaid, not a fix. @CharlesDuffy raised the most important point. Your script isn't dying for no reason. I would look to understand and fix the cause before just setting up a ham-fisted start time kill loop.

Comment: @iamauser there you go... but I don't think you can do much about it anyway.